# Log4j2 manual parsing?

Tags: java, parsing, logging, log4j2

Suppose I'm using a logger introduced via the lombok-provided @Log4j2 annotation as such :

```
logger.info("Successfully stopped communication process");
```

With this logging pattern in my log4j2.xml file :

```
[SERVICE] [%5p] [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%ex
```

Which produces this output in the eclipse console :

```
[SERVICE] [ INFO] [2020-01-14 19:38:27.184] c.m.m.c.c.CommunicationProcessController : Successfully stopped communication process
```

Is there a way for me to parse "on the fly" a string that I would like to display on say a ListView component as if my Log4j2 config would have displayed it?  In other words, can you parse a log entry without actually logging it, harnessing the configured Log4j2 environment's string building power?

Comment: Every programming question could use the tag “programmatically”—it’s meaningless in this context.

Comment: I see what you mean, i guess I meant using the parsing abilities that are normally done internally by Log4j2 in my code, not sure there's a word for that!

Comment: In any case, maybe you could just make a custom logging endpoint that keeps strings around. There may already be something like that as well. Not entirely sure why you'd want this, but hey.

Comment: It is a weird request I will admit!  I have 2 applications (web app and backend service) that use Log4j2 loggers to write to text logs.  As part of the service app, I made a system log monitor component that I would like to display everything that is logged by both applications.  The log entries are also written to a database but they are not parsed.  I want to somehow register a ListView component to be an output of Log4j2, the way I thought to do this is to pull back the entries from the DB, parse them myself and display them.  Is there a better way?

Comment: I'd use a JSON formatter either via a pattern layout or something like https://github.com/jetbrains-infra/log4j-json-layout. I'd also consider not storing them in a DB as text, rather as data--that way it can be indexed and queried in a reasonable way, or use something like logstash/elastic search/etc but that's a larger discussion.

Comment: it's stored in the DB in a much more organized fashion, source, type, severity, message as separate fields, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem that is solved by things like Splunk or an ELK stack. What you are asking for is a variation of that. The problem can be broken down into:

1. You need to use an appender that writes the logs to some sort of collection point. This could be done via writing to something like Logstash, Flume, or Fluentd that forward the logs or by writing directly to something like Kafka, Elastic Search, your database or some sort of shared cache.
2. Depending on the backing store your UI application then needs to get the events from it and display them.

There really are too many choices for how to do this. It all depends on how simple, reliable, and performant you need it to be.